# Send XML file error 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 39'

Tags: xml, vb.net, api, xmlhttprequest, linq-to-xml

I am attempting to send my XML file through an API.  I have done this no problem by using the below code, however when I try and send the FILE over it will not work,  I am now getting in the browser:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 39.
```

**Without trying to send FILE it works:**

```
' create the Xml that the Msxml2.serverXmlHttp object will send to the Webservice
dim Xml_to_Send
Xml_to_Send = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
Xml_to_Send = Xml_to_Send & "<xmldata>"
Xml_to_Send = Xml_to_Send & "     <Products>"
Xml_to_Send = Xml_to_Send & "          <ProductCode>THE-TEST</ProductCode>"
Xml_to_Send = Xml_to_Send & "          <ProductPrice>100.00</ProductPrice>"
Xml_to_Send = Xml_to_Send & "     </Products>"
Xml_to_Send = Xml_to_Send & "</xmldata>"

oXMLHttp.Send(Xml_to_Send)
```

**But trying to send FILE it does NOT work, here is FULL code.  The file is replicated from the code above so I know the file is good:**

```
    <%@ Page Title="MAIN" Language="vb" Explicit="true" AspCompat="true" %>
    <% 
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("sample.xml")

    ' create the Msxml2.serverXmlHttp object needed to post the Xml to the WebService
    Dim oXMLHttp
    oXMLHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.serverXmlHttp")
    oXMLHttp.open("POST", "http://www.mysite.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=mysite@mysite.com&EncryptedPassword=xxxx&Import=Update", False)
    oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
    oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Action", "xmldata")
    oXMLHttp.setTimeouts(100000, 100000, 600000, 9999999)
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 10800

    ' Send the Xml  
    oXMLHttp.Send(String.Format("{0}\n\r{1}", doc.Declaration.ToString(), doc.ToString()))

    ' Receive the Xml
    Dim Xml_Returned
    Xml_Returned = oXMLHttp.responseText

    ' Validate the Xml
    Dim xmlDoc
    xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.loadXML(Xml_Returned)
    If (Len(xmlDoc.text) = 0) Then
        Xml_Returned = ("<BR><B>ERROR in Response xml:<BR>ERROR DETAILS:</B><BR><HR><BR>") & Xml_Returned
    End If

    ' Display the Xml on the browser
    Response.Write(Xml_Returned)

    ' clean up
    Xml_to_Send = Nothing
    oXMLHttp = Nothing
    doc = Nothing
    xmlDoc = Nothing
    Xml_Returned = Nothing        
%>
```

**UPDATE**
I have updated the above code from the response below.  I am now getting in the browser:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 39.
```

Here is the XML I am sending as a test:

```
<xmldata>
  <Products>
    <ProductCode>AMN-ACE14</ProductCode>
    <ProductPrice>3800.00</ProductPrice>
  </Products>
</xmldata>
```

Comment: What language is this?  In vb[a] you can't declare and assign in one line...

Comment: I'm sorry, it is in an .aspx page using VB

Comment: What in the world are you doing? Why would you use XmlHttpRequest from a .NET program?

Comment: I am trying to send an XML file through to an API post.  I couldn't find how to do it through C#, Batch, or Javascript.  This process will eventually be automated and this was the only sampling I had to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to send the content of the document, not the XmlDocument object (as this class is not serializable). The following line should do the trick using an XDocument:

```
oXMLHttp.Send(string.Format("{0}\n\r{1}", doc.Declaration.ToString(), doc.ToString()))
```

If using an XmlDocument the following code will work:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument

doc = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("sample.xml")

oXMLHttp.Send(doc.OuterXml)
```

Comment: Ok makes sense.  I believe VB.NET doesnt allow me to enter it though.  It's giving me `'OuterXml' is not a member of 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument'`

Comment: @ToddN - Sorry, I missed that you were using an XDocument and not an XmlDocument. Please see my amended answer.

Comment: Ahh thank you.  It doesn't work, in chrome it gives me an error `False Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 39`.  Is there a way I can just use `XmlDocument` instead of `XDocument`, it looks much easier to use?

Comment: @ToddN - Have you compared the string being sent from the XDocument with the example string that works in your first example code? You could add the XML generated to your question so I can take a look. See code in answer on how to use an XmlDocument.

Comment: Wow that did it.  I needed to put it as an 'XmlDocument', thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If your code above your not sending the XML but a string that reads "sample.xml"

```
oXMLHttp.Send("sample.xml")
```

Should you be sending the doc object?

```
oXMLHttp.Send(doc)
```

Comment: Yes your correct I was fiddling with it and never changed it back.  It now does nothing as mentioned in the post still, but thanks for catching that!

Comment: Have you debugged 'dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("sample.xml")
' to make sure doc does contain the XML?

Comment: I believe I have by using `Response.Write(doc)`.  Which spits out whats in the XML in my browser..although its still not uploading it, rather just displaying it.

Comment: Is oXMLHttp.responseXML populated after you call oXMLHttp.send(doc)? If so, what does it read?

Comment: interesting, the result displays nothing.